Mapstruct - map flat join list into structured list
Suppose I have a List<Flat> of objects that comes from a JOIN of two database tables.
class Flat {
    String a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3;
}

The natural question is to "unflatten" data, into new classes
class A {
    String a1,a2,a3;
    List<B> children;
}
class B {
    String b1,b2,b3;
}

So I search for some "unflat" mapping method:
List<A> map(List<Flat> source)

Please notiche that target list has usually less items than source list.
What is my best option with mapstruct?
There are many similar questions online, however usually they ask for the inverse mapping (see e.g. https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/discussions/3714)
--Edit---
I will add an example.
Let's assume the source list contains the following items:
new Flat("aa", "aa", "aa", "1", "1", "1")
new Flat("aa", "aa", "aa", "2", "2", "2")
new Flat("bb", "bb", "bb", "3", "3", "3")
new Flat("aa", "aa", "aa", "4", "4", "4")

the target list should contain two items
new A("aa", "aa", "aa")
new A("bb", "bb", "bb")

first target item contains 3 children (n. 1,2,4), while second target item contains 1 child (n.3).

Something like this should help:
@Mapper
public interface FlatMapper {

    List<A> mapList(List<Flat> list);

    @Mapping(target = "children", source = "f")
    A map(Flat f);

    B mapToB(Flat f);

    default List<B> mapToListB(Flat f) {
        return List.of(mapToB(f));
    }
}

I expect those classes have proper getters and setters.
EDIT
MapStruct can't do what you want. You need custom grouping logic.

No, this is not what I mean. In your mapping, target list will have the same number of items of source, and "children" lists will always have exactly 1 item. I will write an example to better explain what I am searching for.
